# Validate user using BCryptPasswordEncoder issue

Tags: java, spring

I have been trying to encode the password of a user in a login register feature on Spring MVC.

I know I should be using `passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword)` however I am unsure as to how to retrieve the encoded password from the database.

The following is my code:

```
public User validateUser(Login login) {

String rawPassword = login.getPassword();

String sql = "select * from users where username='" + login.getUsername() + "' and 
password='" + passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword)
+ "'";
List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserMapper());
return users.size() > 0 ? users.get(0) : null;
}
}

class UserMapper implements RowMapper<User> {
public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
User user = new User();
user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
user.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstname"));
user.setLastname(rs.getString("lastname"));
user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
user.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
return user;
}
}
```

Comment: first get the entry from database . And verify if its same as the encoded version of vrawPassword

Comment: Thats the thing im unsure as to how to get the entry from the database

Comment: Why are you doing this yourself? The fact that you have a `BCryptPasswordEncoder` means you are using Spring Security. But this is working around spring security. Use the framework, don't work around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't try to compare them at the query level like that. Even if you tried to check the encoded version of the raw value it wouldn't work; you have to get the value of the stored encoded password and then see if it matches using bcrypt.

```
// Remove the password check in the query
String sql = "select * from users where username='" + login.getUsername() + "'";
// You'll have a list of users for that username.
List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserMapper());
```

At this point, I'd say, you have a bit of a problem. If your usernames are not unique as suggested in your code, you're going to have to filter the users down to those that have a matching password; can you guarantee there will only be one?

In any case, at this point you're working with basic Java code. Whatever logic you apply in a loop or filter to get a single user to login, you need to compare the passwords like so:

```
boolean matched = passwordEncoder.match(rawPassword, user.getPassword());
```